# Reading Tokens in Java

Tags: java, split, token

While doing a school project I've been running into the following problem: After feeding a line into the `processCommand()` method from the `run()` method (using the console as a sort of text editor), I find that for whatever reason the tokens aren't reading properly and so I run to the 'else' clause of the `processCommand()` method even when the command should be simple and accurate (i.e. typing h into the console puts out "Please enter a valid command."). I'm sure there's something wrong with how I'm splitting the line, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me?

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;

    try {
        do {
            System.out.print("vi: ");
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            if(line.length() > 0){
                processCommand(line);
            }
        } while (!quit);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
    }

    scanner.close();
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}

@Override
public void processCommand(String line) {
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    if(tokens[0] == "b") {
        insertBefore(line.substring(3));
    }
    if(tokens[0] == "i") {
        insertAfter(line.substring(3));
    }
    if(tokens[0] == "m") {
        moveUp(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(3)));
    }
    if(tokens[0] == "u") {
        moveDown(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(3)));
    }
    if(tokens[0] == "r") {
        remove(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(3)));
    }
    if(tokens[0] == "d") {
        remove(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(3)));
    }
    if(tokens[0] == "c") {
        clear();
    }
    if(tokens[0] == "s") {
        try {
            save(line.substring(3));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if(tokens[0] == "l") {
        try{
            load(line.substring(3));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
    if(tokens[0] == "h") {
        displayHelp();
    }
    if(tokens[0] == "x") {
        exit();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid command.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using "==" for string comparison. Use the following:

```
if(tokens[0].equals("h"))...
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here's an alternate version using a switch statement (perhaps easier to read or fewer characters to type):

```
public void processCommand(String line) {
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    if(tokens[0].length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid command.");
        return;
    }
    switch(tokens[0].charAt(0)) {
        case 'b':  insertBefore(line.substring(3));
                   break;
        case 'i':  insertAfter(line.substring(3));
                   break;
        case 'm':  moveUp(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(3)));
                   break;
        case 'u':  moveDown(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(3)));
                   break;
        case 'r':
        case 'd':  remove(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(3)));
                   break;
        case 'c':  clear();
                   break;
        case 's':  try {
                       save(line.substring(3));
                   } catch (IOException e) { }
                   break;
        case 'l':  try {
                       load(line.substring(3));
                   } catch (IOException e) { }
                   break;
        case 'h':  displayHelp();
                   break;
        case 'x':  exit();
                   break;
        default:   System.out.println("Please enter a valid command.");
    }
}
```